In basic terms, what is the difference between Iranaean theodicy and Hick's theodicy?
I'm revising for my GCSE RS paper, so I don't need that much detail or accuracy, just the fundamental ways in which they differ. I understand that there are minor differences but it just seems like Hick re-explains Iranaean theodicy? I am aware that there is another very similar question but I didn't really understand the answers.
Thanks!
